# C++ -- Get internal pointer to a vector

Tags: c++

I use the following method to get an allocated memory space without worrying about how to reclaim the allocated resource.

```
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    vector<int> vecInts;

    for(int iInd=0; iInd<10; i++)
        vecInts.push_back(iInd);

    int* pInt = &vecInts[0]; // Is this a good method?

    // now can I use pInt to modify the value of the vecInts?
    // I will NOT resize the vector and just simply manipulate the values inside
    return 0;
}
```

However, I am not sure whether such a method is a good one or not.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's fine given the precautions you mention (and other obvious ones, like not using a pointer into a vector that's gone out of scope etc.).  The pointer will be valid and invalidated in the exact same way that an iterator into the container would be.

Comment: Can we call this a Hack? Since the std::vector doesn't provide a function called const T* Get? -- thank you

Comment: No, this is not a hack. A vector is supposed to be used in places where a C program would use an array.

Comment: Not reasonably in my opinion.  It's well known to be safe, and is sometimes useful. For example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B) illustrates using such a pointer with calls to `memcpy` and `printf`.  If you're more comfortable with iterators, you can always use one instead, even if perhaps only to get the address ala `&(*v.begin())` (similarly only valid when `v.size() > 0`).

Answer (score 3):

That's a fine method. The memory will be freed automatically when the vector goes out of scope. In modern STL implementations `vector` has a method `data()` which returns the pointer to the start of the memory, which is equivalent to `&v[0]`, but looks much cleaner.

This approach also has the nice property that each element is set to 0 (or default-constructed if it's an object).

For efficiency, if you know the length of the vector in advance, you can supply it as a constructor argument. Then all the memory will be allocated once. E.g.

```
vector<char> buffer(bufSize);
fread(buffer.data(), 1, buffer.size(), file);
```

And, like you mention in the comment, be aware that `buffer.data()` will change if the buffer is resized, and deallocated when it goes out of scope.